# Entity Framework - Linq query with order by and group by

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

I have `Measurement` Objects with the relevant Properties `CreationTime` (DateTime) and `Reference` (String) and some other values.

I'd like to write an efficient linq query to a `DbContext` that

- groups my `Measurement` objects by a given `Reference`
- orders the groups by either the `CreationTime` Property of the first `Measurement` from the group or the average of the `CreationTime` properties
- limits the query to the most recent `numOfEntries`

(In a later step i calculate averaged values over these returned groups, but i guess that's not relevant for my problem.)

The DbContext itself has a `DbSet<Measurement>` called `Measurements`holding all `Measurement` objects.

I came up with the following query, that results in a List of groups that is ordered correctly but is missing some groups in between.

```
var groupByReference = (from m in context.Measurements
                          orderby m.CreationTime
                          group m by new { m.Reference } into g
                          select g).Take(numOfEntries).ToList();
```

How do I select the "most recent" groups of `Measurement`s correctly?

I'm using Entity Framework 4.4 with a MySQL Database (MySql Connector/Net 6.6.4). This example is simplified, i can go into more detail and/or give an example if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of calculating the "Average of the CreationTime", have you considered calculating the timespan from a given point and then determining the average of those timespans then calculating the resulting date based on the given point and the average timespan?

Answer (score 15):

It's method syntax (which I find easier to read) but this might do it

**Updated post comment**

Use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.First()`

With regard to the dates average, you may have to drop that ordering for the moment as I am unable to get to an IDE at the moment

```
var groupByReference = context.Measurements
                              .GroupBy(m => m.Reference)
                              .Select(g => new {Creation = g.FirstOrDefault().CreationTime, 
//                                              Avg = g.Average(m => m.CreationTime.Ticks),
                                                Items = g })
                              .OrderBy(x => x.Creation)
//                            .ThenBy(x => x.Avg)
                              .Take(numOfEntries)
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I got an `NotSupportedException` trying to determine g.First() because `g` is not a final query operation. Trying to average over the `CreationTime` Property failed because it's not an `int`.

Comment: I've updated my answer but I am not going to be able to fix the average date issue until I get to an IDE

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried this in the meantime and also added a 'Ticks' Property which stores the CreationTime as a long so that '.Average()' should work. Now i am getting MySQL Exceptions that say either "Unknown column 'Distinct1.Reference' in 'where clause'" (FirstOrDefault) or "Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K2' in 'field list'" (Average). Is a MySql Connector Bug the possible cause for this? (I should mention that the real query is a bit more complex, i don't query a DbSet directly but use another query as source.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to cast the result of GroupBy and Take into an Enumerable first then process the rest (building on the solution provided by NinjaNye

```
var groupByReference = (from m in context.Measurements
                              .GroupBy(m => m.Reference)
                              .Take(numOfEntries).AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(g => new {Creation = g.FirstOrDefault().CreationTime, 
                                             Avg = g.Average(m => m.CreationTime.Ticks),
                                                Items = g })
                              .OrderBy(x => x.Creation)
                              .ThenBy(x => x.Avg)
                              .ToList() select m);
```

Your sql query would look similar (depending on your input) this

```
SELECT TOP (3) [t1].[Reference] AS [Key]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Reference]
    FROM [Measurements] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[Reference]
    ) AS [t1]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @x1 NVarChar(1000) = 'Ref1'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[CreationTime], [t0].[Id], [t0].[Reference]
FROM [Measurements] AS [t0]
WHERE @x1 = [t0].[Reference]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @x1 NVarChar(1000) = 'Ref2'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[CreationTime], [t0].[Id], [t0].[Reference]
FROM [Measurements] AS [t0]
WHERE @x1 = [t0].[Reference]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `order by` after `group by`:

```
var groupByReference = (from m in context.Measurements
                        group m by new { m.Reference } into g
                        order by g.Avg(i => i.CreationTime)
                        select g).Take(numOfEntries).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried that, but got an error that `DateTime`cannot be converted to `int`. I also tried with an `int` property for testing purposes and got a MySqlException saying something like "Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K2' in 'field list'"

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are all over the place, but this is the solution to my understanding of them:

To group by Reference property:

```
var refGroupQuery = (from m in context.Measurements
            group m by m.Reference into refGroup
            select refGroup);
```

Now you say you want to limit results by "most recent numOfEntries" - I take this to mean you want to limit the returned Measurements...  in that case:

```
var limitedQuery = from g in refGroupQuery
                   select new
                   {
                       Reference = g.Key,
                       RecentMeasurements = g.OrderByDescending( p => p.CreationTime ).Take( numOfEntries )
                   }
```

To order groups by first Measurement creation time (note you should order the measurements; if you want the earliest CreationTime value, substitue "g.SomeProperty" with "g.CreationTime"):

```
var refGroupsOrderedByFirstCreationTimeQuery = limitedQuery.OrderBy( lq => lq.RecentMeasurements.OrderBy( g => g.SomeProperty ).First().CreationTime );
```

To order groups by average CreationTime, use the Ticks property of the DateTime struct:

```
var refGroupsOrderedByAvgCreationTimeQuery = limitedQuery.OrderBy( lq => lq.RecentMeasurements.Average( g => g.CreationTime.Ticks ) );
```