# How to select columns after group by in entitiy frame

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, group-by

I am trying to select multiple columns after groupby operation in EF.

Here is what I want to do:

```
this._context.dbtablename
             .Select(u => new { u.name, u.age, u.grade })
             .GroupBy(x => x.grade)
             .Select(g => new { name = g.?, age = g.??, grade = u.key, Count = g.Count() })
```

Example:

```
name age grade
A     12    8
B     12    9
C     11    10
D     11    9
```

I want to have:

```
name age grade
A     12  8
B     12  9        ----> "name" is B or D, "age" is "12" or "11", does not matter.
C     11  10
```

Can I achieve it?

Comment: if it's grouped then g would be a collection... if you're just selecting the fields like that then why group

Comment: Please see my new edits.

Comment: What is the problem what have you try?

Comment: I do not know how to select columns after groupby:  "Select(g => new { UserId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).OrderByDescending( u => u.Count).Take(maxCount==0?Users.Count:3)."

Comment: If as you said the actual element from the group doesn't matter, then simply use `g.FirstOrDefault().Property`

Comment: Maybe this example help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571878/entity-framework-linq-query-with-order-by-and-group-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each grouped item has a key and collection so you can use first() or firstordefault() to get first item in each group

```
this._context.dbtablename
                .Select(u => new { u.name, u.age, u.grade })
                .GroupBy(a => a.grade)
                .Select(a => new { name = a.First().name, age = a.First().age, grade = a.Key, count = a.Count() });
```

or min() or max()

```
.Select(a => new { name = a.Min(b => b.name), age = a.Min(b => b.age), grade = a.Key, count = a.Count() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Following returns number of valid orders (where clause) in periods (YearMonth YYYYMM):

```
GM_ORDER.AsQueryable()
    .Where(s => s.STATUS > -1)
    .Select(s => new { DateOfOrder = s.CREATEDON.Date, s.ORDERID })
    .GroupBy(g =>  g.DateOfOrder.Year*100 + g.DateOfOrder.Month )
    .OrderByDescending(o=>o.Key)
    .Select(g => new { Period = g.Key, NrOfOrders = g.Count()} )
```

Output is:

```
Period NrOfOrders    
201705 13 
201704 34 
201703 42 
201702 17 
201701 17 
201612 25 
201611 34 
201610 54 
201609 135 
201608 163 
201607 110 
201606 169 
201605 100 
201604 56 
201603 19 
201602 8 
201601 6
```

Hope this helps.

Edited:

---

If you like to see more columns from the grouping following will help. To sort, you need to take it into a list variable and then sort the list variable in itself.

```
GM_ORDER.AsQueryable()
    .Where(s => s.STATUS > -1)
    .Select(s => new { DateOfOrder = s.CREATEDON.Date, s.ORDERID, s.STATUS })
    .GroupBy(g => new { YYYYMM = g.DateOfOrder.Year * 100 + g.DateOfOrder.Month, g.STATUS })
    .Select(g => new { Period = g.Key.YYYYMM, Status = g.Key.STATUS, NrOfOrders = g.Count() })
    .ToList()
```